# What is the content of the tweets that Canan Kaftancıoğlu was sentenced for?

Tags: terrorism, turkey

There are lots of articles writing about the prosecution of Canan Kaftancıoğlu. For example [this](https://www.pes.eu/news_content.php?id=1561), [this](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2022/may/12/key-opposition-leader-banned-from-politics-after-anti-erdogan-tweet) and [this](https://www.bbc.com/turkce/haberler-turkiye-61426730) all come right after their wikipedia page when I search her name.

I'm not doing a very good job of finding the content of the tweets though. The Guardian mentions that the tweets were

> insulting a public official, publicly insulting the republic of
> Turkey, and insulting the president, Recep Tayyip Erdoğan, in tweets
> accusing him of theft

but doesn't offer the actual content, translated or otherwise. That doesn't sound like terrorism to me. But maybe the Guardian is not painting an accurate picture of what was said.

On the other hand, [this](https://factsofturkey.org/opinion/3166-the-reality-of-canan-kaftancioglu) article from some relatively unknown news source paints a very different picture of what was said;

> tweets praising countless terrorist organizations. One of them is
> TKP-ML, a designated Maoist-Lenninist terrorist organization.
> Kaftancıoğlu tweeted about one of its top members saying “thousand
> salutes to the general...” acknowledging a terrorist as a general
> while failing to acknowledge the founder father of Turkey, Atatürk.
> She goes on to tweet about Sakine Cansız, one of the leading members
> of terrorist PKK, giving examples of her speeches and calling Cansız a
> revolutionary.

That's a direct quote, and goes into a lot more detail about what was said. However, I've never heard of this website, and I don't know if they are just making things up, or taking them so drastically out of context that the meaning is warped.

I'd like to find the actual tweets she was prosecuted for, rather than another interpretation of what they said. While the interpretations certainly add value by explaining the cultural background, they don't replace the originals.

So;

1. How many tweets were used as evidence in the prosecution?
2. Are they archived anywhere that I can read them? In Turkish or translated.

Comment: Have you tried looking for the actual sentence of the case? Those are often public, and could provide a detailed description of the evidence that has been considered for the decision. Of course, you will probably need to search for it in Turkish.

Answer (score 4):

The [decision](https://medyascope.tv/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/Canan-Kaftanciog%CC%86lu-Yargitay-I%CC%87lami.pdf) from the Court of Cassation seems to contain the full content of the tweets for which Kaftancıoğlu was sentenced. My Turkish isn't really sufficient to provide a completely accurate translation, but I've given it a go below:

| Date | Content | Translation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 31/05/2013 | günün özeti. Ben yazmadım miki yazdı! (Attached to an image of graffiti reading "O... Ç... TAYİP") | Summary of the day. I didn't write it, Miki wrote it! |
| 26/12/2013 | RTE 'asıl hedef benim' diyor, hedef değil asıl hırsız sensin! | RTE says 'I am the main target', you are the real thief, not the target! |
| 23/03/2014 | Şiştt sessiz olun RTE kapattığını sanıyor. Salak!... | Crap be quiet RTE thinks he's turned it off. Idiot!... |
| 02/08/2014 | Kılıçdaroğlu: Alevi Demirtaş: Zaza Erdoğan: Hırsız | Kılıçdaroğlu: Alevi Demirtaş: Zaza Erdoğan: Thief |
| 25/08/2013 | Sahi devlet katil olmak yerine kahraman olmayı seçseydi ne güzel olurdu! | It would be nice if the state chose to be a hero instead of a murderer! |
| 12/07/2014 | ...Derin devlet diyerek olaya mistizm katıyor ve asıl devleti aklıyoruz aslında. Bu cinayetleri devlet işledi...! | ...By saying the deep state, we add mysticism to the event and we justify the real state. These murders were committed by the state...! |
| 12/05/2014 | ... Hrant'da da dinlememiş miydik? Boşuna demiyoruz devlet katil değil seri katil diye. Öfkeliyim çok! | ...Didn't we listen in Hrant too? We do not say for nothing that the state is a serial killer, not a murderer. I am very angry! |
| 11/03/2014 | Devlet katil değil seri katil.. #HoşçakalBerkinim | The state is not a murderer, it is a serial killer.. #HoşçakalBerkinim |
| 20/10/2014 | Nasıl söylesem ama, ilk harflere baksana... "Hırsız Tayyip"... | How can I say it, but look at the first letters... "Thief Tayyip"... |
| 11/01/2013 | İnsanlık tarihi kadın ile başlar. İnsanlık kadına yapılanlarla kaybeder demiş Sakine Cansız. Ve insanlık yine kaybetti. | Human history begins with women. Sakine Cansız said that humanity loses with what is done to women. And humanity lost again. |